# "A Must have" ND filter stops for filming with Canon 5D Mk2?

Tags: dslr, filming, filter

The question is - which stops (ND 0.6, ND 0.9.....) are the most frequently used?
I am currently choosing Tiffen ones and since there are plenty of different stops to choose from and I have nearly no experience in using ND filters  - your suggestions would be highly apreciated

Comment: Are you stuck on Tiffen? I've read that Hoya ProND are some of the best ND filters you can get. Check out some comparison tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "most used".  You use whatever is appropriate for the exposure conditions you have and the desired aperture and shutter speed (and ISO, though turning down ISO is almost always better than using an ND filter if it is an option).  The more light you have, the more wide open the aperture and the slower the shutter speed, the heavier the weight of the ND filter you need.

Comment: Thanks for teh answer. let me clarify a bit:
I need my camcorder's setting to be constant at: 
exposure 50
aperture: f2.8 (or, as open as posisble...let's say up to f1.4)
iso: 100/160 max
and I am about to shoot in the middle of a brigh sunlit day.